Existence of a complemented basic sequence
Let $X$ be an infinite-dimensional Banach space (complex or real). A subspace of $X$ means a closed linear submanifold. If $S$ is a non-empty subset of $X$, then $[S]$ denotes the closed linear span of $S$, that is, the smallest subspace containing $S$. A subspace $M$ of $X$ is complemented in $X$ if there exists a subspace $N$ of $X$ such that $M\cap N=\{0\}$ and $M+N=X$.
A sequence $(e_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset X$ is a Schauder basic sequence if for every $x\in [(e_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}]$ there exists a unique sequence of scalars $(\alpha_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\alpha_n e_n$. A Schauder basic sequence $(e_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is complented if the subspace $[(e_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}]$ is complemented in $X$.
I question whether a complemented Schauder basic sequence exists in every infinite-dimensional Banach space $X$.

No. Google "hereditarily indecomposable Banach spaces" to see that there exist separable Banach spaces in which all complemented subspaces are either of finite dimension or of finite codimension. Some HI spaces fail the approximation property, which implies that no finite codimensional subspace has a Schauder basis.

Thank you for the answer! What about non-separable spaces? A question related to the question that I have asked is whether in every non-separable Banach space there exist quasi-complementary subspaces M and N which are not complementary (that is, M+N is dense in X but not closed). I hoped that with basic sequences I could imitate a well known construction for Hilbert spaces.

Well, if $X$ has a separable quotient, then $X$ has a quotient that has a Schauder basis by an old result of Rosenthal and me. Even if no separable infinite dimensional subspace of $X$ that has a basis is complemented, you can still get a quotient with a basis s.t. the basis vectors in the quotient are the image of a basic sequence in $X$. Then the kernel of the quotient map and the closed linear span of the basic sequence gives a quasicomplementary decomposition of $X$.

But it is a famous open problem whether every infinite dimensional Banach space has a separable infinite dimensional quotient space.

Thank you for your comments. I see now that the problem of whether there exist quasi-complementary subspaces which are not complementary is harder than I expected.

Here is a slightly easier problem. Does every nonseparable Banach space have a closed nonseparable subspace that is not of finite codimension? The answer is obviously yes if every Banach space has a quasicomplementary decompostion.
